# I'm trying to make an if statements that sorts different types of values in my array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, console.log

I want a code that gives me the value of the objects properties value, and then take the if statement that has that value so it gets the correct console.log.

array with object.

```
var stoneData = [];
stoneData.push({type:"lineTo", point:"test", axis:{x:0, y:0}} + ' = test data 1');
stoneData.push( ' ' + {type:"moveTo", point:"test", axis:{x:0, y:0}} + ' = test data 2');
stoneData.push(' ' + {type:"quadraticCurveTo", point:"test", axis:{curveX:0, curveY:0, x:0, y:0}} + '=  test data 3');
```

If statement

```
    var i = 0;
if(stoneData[i].type == "moveTo" || stoneData[i].type == "lineTo" ) {
console.log('stoneData[' + i + '].type = ' + stoneData[i].type + ', stoneData[' + i + '].point = ' + stoneData[i].point + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.x = ' + stoneData[i].axis.x + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.y = ' + stoneData[i].axis.y);
} else if(stoneData[i].type == "quadraticCurveTo") {
  console.log('stoneData[' + i + '].type = ' + stoneData[i].type + ', stoneData[' + i + '].point = ' + stoneData[i].point + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.curveX = ' + stoneData[i].axis.curveX + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.curveY = ' + stoneData[i].axis.curveY + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.x = ' + stoneData[i].axis.x + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.y = ' + stoneData[i].axis.y);
} else {
  return console.log("something went wrong");
}
//next console.log(stoneData[i]);
 i += 1;
 if(stoneData[i].type == "moveTo" || stoneData[i].type == "lineTo" ) {
 console.log('stoneData[' + i + '].type = ' + stoneData[i].type + ', stoneData[' + i + '].point = ' + stoneData[i].point + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.x = ' + stoneData[i].axis.x + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.y = ' + stoneData[i].axis.y);
 } else if(stoneData[i].type == "quadraticCurveTo") {
   console.log('stoneData[' + i + '].type = ' + stoneData[i].type + ', stoneData[' + i + '].point = ' + stoneData[i].point + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.curveX = ' + stoneData[i].axis.curveX + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.curveY = ' + stoneData[i].axis.curveY + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.x = ' + stoneData[i].axis.x + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.y = ' + stoneData[i].axis.y);
 } else {
   return console.log("something went wrong");
 }
```

I have tried different other methods also.

I can't find the correct way of finding (`stoneData[index].type == value`).

I have done programming less than a year, so I'm not so good with advance answers yet.

This is the new code:

```
var stoneData = [];
stoneData.push({type:"lineTo", point:"test", axis:{x:0, y:0}} + ' = test data 1');
stoneData.push( ' ' + {type:"moveTo", point:"test", axis:{x:0, y:0}} + ' = test data 2');
stoneData.push(' ' + {type:"quadraticCurveTo", point:"test", axis:{curveX:0, curveY:0, x:0, y:0}} + '=  test data 3');

    function consoleTheData() {
//log the data
console.log('stoneData = ' + stoneData);
console.log('stoneData.length in index = ' + (stoneData.length - 1));
for (let i = 0; i < stoneData.length; i++) {
switch (stoneData[i].type) {
  case "moveTo":
  case "lineTo":
    console.log('stoneData[' + i + '].type = ' + stoneData[i].type + ', stoneData[' + i + '].point = ' + stoneData[i].point + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.x = ' + stoneData[i].axis.x + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.y = ' + stoneData[i].axis.y);
    break;
  case "quadraticCurveTo":
    console.log('stoneData[' + i + '].type = ' + stoneData[i].type + ', stoneData[' + i + '].point = ' + stoneData[i].point + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.curveX = ' + stoneData[i].axis.curveX + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.curveY = ' + stoneData[i].axis.curveY + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.x = ' + stoneData[i].axis.x + ', stoneData['+i+'].axis.y = ' + stoneData[i].axis.y);
    break;
  default:
    console.log("something went wrong");
}
}
}
consoleTheData();
```

Comment: hasOwnProperty returns a bolean (true or false), not the value of the property
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
const stoneData = [
    { type: "moveTo", point: 112, axis: { x: 123, y: 123 } },
    { type: "lineTo", point: 112, axis: { x: 123, y: 123 } },
    { type: "moveTo", point: 112, axis: { x: 123, y: 123 } },
    { type: "quadraticCurveTo", point: 112, axis: { x: 123, y: 123 } },
    { type: "xxy", point: 112, axis: { x: 123, y: 123 } }
];


stoneData.map((stone) =>        
        switch (stone.type) {
            case "moveTo":
            case "lineTo":
                console.log("case 1 - lineTo or moveTo" );
                break;
            case "quadraticCurveTo":
                console.log("case 2 quadraticCurveTo ");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("something went wrong");
        }
});
```

output

```
case 1 - lineTo or moveTo
case 1 - lineTo or moveTo
case 1 - lineTo or moveTo
case 2 quadraticCurveTo 
something went wrong
```

same with for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < stoneData.length; i ++) {

    switch (stoneData[i].type) {
        case "moveTo":
        case "lineTo":
            console.log("case 1 - lineTo or moveTo");
            break;
        case "quadraticCurveTo":
            console.log("case 2 quadraticCurveTo ");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("something went wrong");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How to do it, when using index? I did with index, it went to "something went wrong"? I never used "stoneData.map((stone) => ", because, I don't know what it does.

Comment: @DerekPK  The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Added the same solution using a for loop (index)

Comment: map isn't a good example, better use forEach  method

Comment: I added the switch statement to the code as you can see in the edit, still not working, getting 4 "something went wrong" now.

Comment: but why do you store `stoneData` in that format? adding those `..} + ' = test data 1'` makes the data an array of strings. my solution is taking an array of objects, so of corse it will not work as using your data, `stoneData[i].type` will return `undefined`

Comment: It's so I see easier, when I `console.log(stoneData);`